# Efficient way to select all values from one column not in another column

Tags: sql, performance, distinct, notin

I need to return all values from `colA` that are not in `colB` from `mytable`. I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(colA) FROM mytable WHERE colA NOT IN (SELECT colB FROM mytable)
```

It is working however the query is taking an excessively long time to complete.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `NOT IN` slows down as the set size grows, and there's often a limit to how many rows can be in the `NOT IN` clause.  Outside of small result sets I've found it better to use other means to get the difference between two result sets.

Comment: When talking about performance, you must name your RDBMS or get suboptimal answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In standard SQL there are **no parentheses** in `DISTINCT colA`. `DISTINCT` is not a function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA
FROM   mytable
WHERE  colA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT colB FROM mytable);
```

Added `DISTINCT` to the sub-select as well. If you have many duplicates it could speed up the query.

A CTE might be faster, depending on your DBMS. I additionally demonstrate `LEFT JOIN` as alternative to exclude the values in `valB`, and an alternative way to get distinct values with `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT colB FROM mytable GROUP BY colB)
SELECT m.colA
FROM   mytable m
LEFT   JOIN x ON x.colB = m.colA
WHERE  x.colB IS NULL
GROUP  BY m.colA;
```

Or, simplified further, and with a plain subquery (probably fastest):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.colA
FROM   mytable m
LEFT   JOIN mytable x ON x.colB = m.colA
WHERE  x.colB IS NULL;
```

There are **basically 4 techniques** to exclude rows with keys present in another (or the same) table:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

The deciding factor for speed will be **indexes**. You need to have indexes on `colA` and `colB` for this query to be fast.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried: `SELECT DISTINCT m1.colA FROM mytable m1 LEFT JOIN mytable m2 ON (m1.colA = m2.colB) WHERE m2.colA IS NULL ORDER BY m1.colA ASC` and it is several orders of magnitude faster and seems to be working - is this equivalent to the code I posted in the question? It's so much quicker that I'm suspicious I might have missed something.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, you got a typo in your query. Must be `WHERE m2.colB IS NULL`. The (corrected) query might be faster with `LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT colB FROM mytable) m2 ON m2.colB = m1.colA` **if** there are many duplicate values for `colB`.

Comment: @Andrew: `m2.colA` is always `NULL` if `m2.colB` is NULL here, but `m2.colA` can be NULL even if `m2.colB` is not. So the correct (and faster!) form here is: `WHERE m2.colB IS NULL`. **If** `colA` is defined NOT NULL, then your above query is correct.

Comment: Thanks, the queries are giving me the same number of results I suppose because there are no `NULL` values. Do you know why it is so much faster?

Comment: @Andrew: Different query plans perform differently. I can't say much without knowing which RDBMS you are using. You might want to edit that information into your question. Information about indexes would be instrumental, too.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. I made the `DISTINCT` change you suggested and it now completes in a few seconds.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `exists`:

```
select distinct
    colA
from
    mytable m1
where
    not exists (select 1 from mytable m2 where m2.colB = m1.colA)
```

`exists` does a semi-join to quickly match the values. `not in` completes the entire result set and then does an `or` on it. `exists` is typically faster for values in tables.

Comment: @Andrew - Sure! It says, grab the distinct `colA`s where there's no row from `mytable` that `colB` is equal to that `colA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`EXCEPT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersect_%28sql%29#EXCEPT_operator) operator which effectively diffs two `SELECT` queries.  `EXCEPT DISTINCT` will return only unique values.  Oracle's [`MINUS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator is equivalent to `EXCEPT DISTINCT`.